# RDkit Trouble When Trying To Calculate Dice Similarity From Molecular Finger Prints

Tags: python, rdkit

**I am Having Trouble when trying to calculate the DiceSimilarity from MorganFingerprints from the BindingDB database. I keep getting an argument error after it runs for about 40% through the database.**

```
`tqdm._instances.clear()
df_matrix = pd.DataFrame()
df_matrix['BindingDB Reactant_set_id'] = df_database['BindingDB Reactant_set_id']
df_matrix.index = list(df_database['BindingDB Reactant_set_id'])
cols = list(df_metabolites['Molecule'])

for i in tqdm(range(len(mol_list2)),desc = 'Calculating Dice Similarity'):
 col = cols[I]
  df_matrix[col] = [DataStructs.DiceSimilarity(mfp2[i],mfp1[j]) for j in range(len(mfp1))]

df_matrix = df_matrix.drop(columns = ['BindingDB Reactant_set_id'])
```

I am getting an argument error.

```
 ArgumentError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
    ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_8208/849522583.py in <module>
     7 for i in tqdm(range(len(mol_list2)),desc = 'Calculating Dice Similarity'):
      8   col = cols[i]
----> 9   df_matrix[col] = [DataStructs.DiceSimilarity(mfp2[i],mfp1[j]) for j in range(len(mfp1))]
     10 
     11 df_matrix = df_matrix.drop(columns = ['BindingDB Reactant_set_id'])

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_8208/849522583.py in <listcomp>(.0)
      7 for i in tqdm(range(len(mol_list2)),desc = 'Calculating Dice Similarity'):
      8   col = cols[i]
----> 9   df_matrix[col] = [DataStructs.DiceSimilarity(mfp2[i],mfp1[j]) for j in range(len(mfp1))]
     10 
     11 df_matrix = df_matrix.drop(columns = ['BindingDB Reactant_set_id'])

ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    rdkit.DataStructs.cDataStructs.DiceSimilarity(UIntSparseIntVect, int) did not match C++ signature:
    DiceSimilarity(class RDKit::SparseIntVect<unsigned __int64> siv1, class RDKit::SparseIntVect<unsigned __int64> siv2, bool returnDistance=False, double bounds=0.0)
    DiceSimilarity(class RDKit::SparseIntVect<unsigned int> siv1, class RDKit::SparseIntVect<unsigned int> siv2, bool returnDistance=False, double bounds=0.0)
    DiceSimilarity(class RDKit::SparseIntVect<__int64> siv1, class RDKit::SparseIntVect<__int64> siv2, bool returnDistance=False, double bounds=0.0)
    DiceSimilarity(class RDKit::SparseIntVect<int> siv1, class RDKit::SparseIntVect<int> siv2, bool returnDistance=False, double bounds=0.0)
    DiceSimilarity(class ExplicitBitVect bv1, class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > pkl, bool returnDistance=0)
    DiceSimilarity(class SparseBitVect bv1, class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > pkl, bool returnDistance=0)
    DiceSimilarity(class ExplicitBitVect bv1, class ExplicitBitVect bv2, bool returnDistance=0)
    DiceSimilarity(class SparseBitVect bv1, class Sparse
BitVect bv2, bool returnDistance=0)
```

I was hoping for some help with this, please!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you figure this out yet? The [rdkit tag at MMSE](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rdkit) has 95.5% of its questions answered. If you want this question migrated there, please ping me by typing @Nike in a comment and letting me know. I'll make a case to the moderators for a migration.